# Angularjs manage a big amount data

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a big issue when i retrieve a json file from my server. This json file has 1.2 MB of data. So it's a pretty big file. So, in my init function i do that :

```
$scope.init = function(allmatrix) {
    if (allmatrix.length > 0) {
        $scope.jsonResult = allmatrix[0];
    }
}
```

It means that each time i go to the home page i have to download 1.2MB of data (json data is inside 'allmatrix' variable). So i don't really know how to deal with that because it's not efficient for now. Maybe, i need to cache the data or use a thread in angularjs (because my user interface stay blocked for two minutes). if someone has already faced this issue, could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do, but thats a lot of data.  are you sure you need it every time you load the home page?

1) You can enable compression on your web server.  This will lower the time the data takes to be shipped across the network.  Enabling compression is different depending on what type of web server you are running.  Here is an example for how to do it with tomcat: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

2) Shorten the keys in the json objects that you are transferring.
Json can be pretty repeptive, so try and make it as small as you can.  You sacrifice readability but you can shrink the size of your data significantly.  e.g.
original:

```
[{'longkey1':'val1','longkey2':'val12},{'longkey1':'val3','longkey2':'val14},...]
```

change to something like:

```
[{'a':'val1','b':'val12},{'a':'val3','b':'val14},...]
```

3) You say your home page is blocked until the json data is loaded?  You should be fetching your data asynchronously so that your page can load and display a meaningful 'loading data, please wait' message.  This would be more graceful.  You don't really provide code for how you are getting the json from your sever so its hard to comment much more on that.

4) Because you need to load data every time you hit your home page, it might make sense to convert your website into a single page app.  That way on the first load you can load all the data, and then you can navigate anywhere you want and you don't need to ever reload that json again even when you navigate back to the home page.  Just don't hit refresh!

5) Caching will work well too (perhaps in conjunction with the above) provided the json data you are loading doesn't change frequently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that i am looking for the combination of the third and fourth way. To explain how i fetch the data in my servlet i do this :

Comment: I think that i am looking for the combination of the third and fourth way. To explain how i fetch the data in my servlet i do this : `req.setAttribute( "allMatrix", matrix.readAll());` when i use matrix.readAll() i fetch all the data. and then in angularjs i do this : `ng-init="init(${allMatrix})"` in the home page. So i think that if i can asynchronously fetch data it will be great.